# Dynamically populated select using ajax in WordPress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, forms

I want to use the value from my first dropdown in a MySQL query to generate a second dropdown. I'm doing this in wordpress and have tried to modify code I have used for a form plugin to apply to a coded form. But the code I have doesn't populate the second dropdown.

```
<form id="page-changer" action="" method="post"> <?php

$chart_types = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT page_id, title FROM master_chart WHERE mod_id=$mod_id AND (geo_type=$geo_type OR geo_type IS NULL) ORDER BY sequence" );

    echo '<select id="chart_type" required style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 15px;"><option value="" disabled selected>Select Chart Type</option>';

    foreach ($chart_types as $chart_type) :
        echo '<option value="'.$chart_type->page_id.'">'.$chart_type->title.'</option>';
    endforeach;

    echo '</select>'; ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery('#chart_type').change(function(){
                var chartPOP=jQuery('#chart_type').val();

            jQuery('#response').empty();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url:"<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    type:'POST',
                    data:'action=populate_chart&pageID=' + chartPOP,

                    success:function(results) {
                        jQuery('#response').append(results);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script> <?php

echo '<select id="response"><option value="" disabled selected>Select Frequency</option></select>';

function populate_chart() {

    if( isset( $_POST['pageID'] ) ) :

        $page_id=$_POST['pageID'];

        global $wpdb;

        $frequencies = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT title FROM master_chartmeta WHERE measure >= $measure_toggle AND page_id=$page_id");

        foreach( $results as $rows ) :
            $option .= '<option value="'.$rows->title.'">';
            $option .= $rows->title;
            $option .= '</option>';
        endforeach;

        echo $option;
        die();

    endif;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_populate_chart', populate_chart );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_populate_chart', populate_chart );
```

Comment: You mentioned that when you select an option on the first dropdown the second one doesn't get updated. Are you seeing any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: BTW, there's an error in your `populate_chart()` function: you're trying to use the `$measure_toggle` variable but it doesn't seem you have initialized it anywhere inside your function so of course your query won't work (which, by the way, is completely open to SQL Injection attacks, you should look into `$wpdb->prepare()`).

Comment: Thanks for the advice on prepare. I am getting 400 Bad Request on the ajax URL